# Getting the currently logged in user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get the current logged in user in my express and mongoose app. I have authenticated it with passport but am unable to get the current username. I have tried calling it from the model but is returned by a null value, can someone help me with this? Thanks.

models/User.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String
}) ;
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

app.js

```js
const express               =  require('express'),
      app                   =  express(),
      mongoose              =  require("mongoose"),
      passport              =  require("passport"),
      bodyParser            =  require("body-parser"),
      LocalStrategy         =  require("passport-local"),
      passportLocalMongoose =  require("passport-local-mongoose"),
      User                  =  require("./models/user");
//Connecting database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/auth_demo");
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret:"Any normal Word",       //decode or encode session
    resave: false,          
    saveUninitialized:false    
}));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());       //session encoding
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());   //session decoding
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(
      { extended:true }
))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

...

app.get("/userprofile",isLoggedIn ,(req,res) =>{
    res.render("userprofile", {name: User.username});
})

...

app.listen(process.env.PORT ||3000,function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else {
        console.log("Server Started At Port 3000");
    }
      
});
```

userprofile.ejs

```js
<h1>
    User Profile
</h1>
<p>
    <%= name %>
    After Login the user will reach here.
</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there might be something like `req.user.blabla`

Comment: `res.render("userprofile", {name: User.username});` update this to `    res.render("userprofile", {name: req.user.username});`